# Istio fault tolerance retries is not working

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I deployed the yaml file below, but I am getting a response in a very short time when member service is getting aborted with 500

```
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: retry-member
spec:
  hosts:
  - member
  http:
  - fault:
      delay:
        percent: 50
        fixedDelay: 2s
      abort:
        httpStatus: 500
        percent: 50
    route:
    - destination:
        host: member
    retries:
      attempts: 10
      perTryTimeout: 1s
      retryOn: 5xx
```

Comment: how can i verify that retry is working or not?

Comment: Have You checked envoy access logs?

Comment: yes i checked envoy access logs but there is nothing related to retries in logs

Comment: Which specific port are You testing fault tolerance retries with? Are you testing with `HTTP` error `500`?

Comment: it's working now thank you.